# A cleaner/shorter way to solve this problem?

Tags: python

This exercise is taken from [Google's Python Class](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/edu/languages/google-python-class/index.html):

> D. Given a list of numbers, return a list where
>   all adjacent == elements have been reduced to a single element,
>   so [1, 2, 2, 3] returns [1, 2, 3]. You may create a new list or
>   modify the passed in list.

Here's my solution so far:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  if not nums:
    return nums

  list = [nums[0]]

  for num in nums[1:]:
    if num != list[-1]:
        list.append(num)

  return list
```

But this looks more like a C program than a Python script, and I have a feeling this can be done much more elegant.

**EDIT**

So `[1, 2, 2, 3]` should give `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1, 2, 3, 3, 2]` should give `[1, 2, 3, 2]`

Comment: It sure can be reduced to a single expression. But that won't make it any more readable. Your solution is fine.

Comment: @delnan: It's not bad code, but it can definitely be done better; his analysis is correct that he's doing it the way a C programmer writing Python code would do it.  He obviously wants to learn to do things more elegantly, so I think telling him his "solution is fine", discouraging him from learning how it can be improved, is damaging at best.

Comment: @Glenn: Yes, it can be done better. But when I encountered this in a codebase, I wouldn't curse the dev who wrote it - it's perfectly understandable and reasonable succinct code, not 100% idiomatic, but close enough (hey, at least it's not for i in range(len(nums)) ;) ).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is function in [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) that works here:

```
import itertools
[key for key,seq in itertools.groupby([1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4])]
```

You can also write a generator:

```
def remove_adjacent(items):
    # iterate the items
    it = iter(items)
    # get the first one
    last = next(it)
    # yield it in any case
    yield last
    for current in it:
        # if the next item is different yield it
        if current != last:
            yield current
            last = current
        # else: its a duplicate, do nothing with it

print list(remove_adjacent([1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4]))
```

Comment: `itertools` to the rescue again :)

Comment: This code (the version on top) is what the OP needs to be following.  It doesn't try to force everything into one statement, but it's concise--8 lines of code (excluding the comments, which are obvious enough to be unnecessary outside of a tutorial).  It also has the advantage of working on any iterator, which the `zip`-based solutions don't; that isn't actually required by the question, but it's a very useful property that the OP will want to understand sooner rather than later.  It also works straightforwardly on infinite iterators.

Comment: +1.  Your answer and Ignacio's are both excellent (and similar).  Perhaps Ignacio's use of izip is more pythonic, but I your method was just a little clearer.

Comment: ... the version on bottom, now; for some reason he edited the answer and put the less useful version--which the OP probably won't even be able to understand--on top.  The OP needs to learn the *mechanism* of iterators and generator functions before using itertools.

Comment: I hope everyone reads beyond the first 4 lines then ;-p I think when someone reads the docs about `groupby` he can understand what it does, even if he has no idea how it works. `groupby` can help you a lot when writing a generator is not as simple as here, so I wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 3):

[`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) to the rescue.

```
import itertools

def remove_adjacent(lst):
  i = iter(lst)
  yield next(i)
  for x, y in itertools.izip(lst, i):
    if x != y:
      yield y


L = [1, 2, 2, 3]

print list(remove_adjacent(L))
```

Comment: FWIW: the OP doesn't seem to be at the point where he intuitively understands iterators.  So, I prefer THC4k's generator function answer, since it shows the usage of iterators explicitly, whereas you need to already understand them to understand `izip`.

Answer (score 3):

Solution using list comprehensions, zipping then iterating through a twice. Inefficient, but short and sweet. It also has the problem of extending a[1:] with something.

```
a = [ 1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,3,3 ]

b = [ i for i,j in zip(a,a[1:] + [None]) if not i == j ]
```

Comment: Tim Pietzcker got in there a tiny bit ahead of me ; but mine is a smidgen more 'pythonic' ;)

Comment: -1 for brevity!  This tries too hard to force things into one statement.  Don't confuse being concise with being terse.

Answer (score 2):

This works, but I'm not quite happy with it yet because of the `+[None]` bit to ensure that the last element is also returned...

```
>>> mylist=[1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,5]
>>> [x for x, y in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]+[None]) if x != y]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The most Pythonic way is probably to go the path of least resistance and use `itertools.groupby()` as suggested by THC4K and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def collapse( data ):
...  return list(sorted(set(data)))
... 
>>> collapse([1,2,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Second attempt after the additional requirment was added:

```
>>> def remove_adjacent( data ):
...     last = None
...     for datum in data:
...         if datum != last:
...             last = datum
...             yield datum
...             
>>> list( remove_adjacent( [1,2,2,3,2] ) )
[1, 2, 3, 2]
```

Comment: That was also my first idea, but doesn't work if same elements aren't adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html). Also, here's a [tutorial on Python iterators and generators (pdf)](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aLtZo_DxLjGcJ%3aheather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Python/PyIterGen.pdf+python+iter&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiaLc1Y5ma90UngbCLHgKMWQnU6fOItL9OlFjIBRFC21CPcdd3e8LR51I84KQ7sMYI3JceHf2Enmhk2jvmcczpjBIZ9N2Wu--5Mu0cgpklukXtvLchh8_VGqq52uLXbt_HkwXNm&sig=AHIEtbSwRJgimaInqD5eJWvY7-TlChvpVA).

Answer (score 0):

This is also somewhat functional; it could be written as a one-liner using lambdas but that would just make it more confusing.  In Python 3 you'd need to import reduce from functools.

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  def maybe_append(l, x):
    return l + ([] if len(l) and l[-1] == x else [x])
  return reduce(maybe_append, nums, [])
```